# How to add recursive function checking xhr response in testcafe script?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to write a test download works, which requires to check if xhr response has status READY. I created a client function in TestCafe, using promises, but it's failing in case of recursion.

How should I fix my code to handle this situation?

P.S. many apologies for newbies questions, I have just started my journey in automation testing.

```
fixture`Download report works`


test
    .requestHooks(logger)//connected a request hook, will wait for logger request 
    ('I should be able to download PDF report from header of the page', async t => {
        //recursively check if response status is READY, and then go to assertions

        const waitForDownloadResponseStatus = ClientFunction((log) => {
            return new Promise((resolve,rejects)=>{
                const waitForStatus=()=>{

                        const arrayFromResponse = JSON.parse(log.response.body);
                        const responseStatus = arrayFromResponse.status;
                        if (responseStatus == 'READY')
                        {
                            resolve(responseStatus);
                        } 
                        else {
                            waitForStatus();
                        }
                    }
                waitForStatus();
                })
        });
        //page objects
        const reportTableRaw = Selector('div.contentcontainer').find('a').withText('April 2019').nth(0);
        const downloadPdfButton = Selector('a.sr-button.sr-methodbutton.btn-export').withText('PDF');
        //actions.

        await t
                .navigateTo(url)
                .useRole(admin)       
                .click(reportTableRaw)//went to customise your report layout
                .click(downloadPdfButton)
                .expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200))
                .ok();//checked if there is something in logger
        const logResponse = logger.requests[0];

                // const arrayFromResponse = JSON.parse(logResponse.response.body);
                // const responseStatus = arrayFromResponse.status;

        console.log(logger.requests);
        await waitForDownloadResponseStatus(logResponse).then((resp)=>{
            console.log(resp);
            t.expect(resp).eql('READY');
        });     


    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass an object as an argument or a dependency to a client function, it will receive a copy of the passed object. Thus it won't be able to detect any changes made by external code. In this particular case, the `waitForStatus` function won't reach its termination condition because it can't detect changes in the `log` object made by an external request hook. It means that this function will run indefinitely until it consumes the all available stack memory. After that, it will fail with a stack overflow error.

To avoid this situation, you can check out that response has status `READY` if you change the predicate argument of the `contains` function.
Take a look at the following code:

```
.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200 &&
                                  JSON.parse(record.response.body).status === 'READY'))
.ok({ timeout: 5000 });
```

Also, you can use the `timeout` option. It's the time (in milliseconds) an assertion can take to pass before the test fails.

Comment: Now I understood. And the code you suggested works! no need to write long functions. Thank you for the answer, Andrey!

Comment: We are happy to hear that this code was helpful. May I ask you to mark our answer as a "solution", to make it more discoverable for other users?